# How to filter dates 2 days before today

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Table has a column with dates. I am showing this data with Table visualization. I need to filter the date to always show dates that are 2 days before from now. For example today is 22.04.2020 and I need to filter it so it would automatically show only data with dates 2 days before like 20.04.2020 as a max date. In SQL I use code`DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today)`
Since I'm using direct query then I can't make changes to the date table in query manager ( It needs to be updated every 15 minutes )

How can I do that in Power BI visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, use [relative filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range).
You can define it as a slicer, a hidden slicer or in the filter panel.

Comment: In relative date filtering I can only choose "is in the last..." and "is in this..." and "is in the next..." These all include todays date but I need it to show data 2 days before today. for example today is 23. of april I need it to always show data 2 days before aka 21. of april.